# CSS inside PHP is not showing up, it only gives a blank page

Tags: php, css

My script:

```
<?php
function ceklogin(){
    session_start();
    if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] != 1) {
        header("Location: login.php");
        exit;
    }}
function css(){
echo '
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>OpenWrt Angel Beats! Edition</title>
<div align="center">

.content:before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;

  display: block;
  background-image: url("/http://666a658c624a3c03a6b2-25cda059d975d2f318c03e90bcf17c40.r92.cf1.rackcdn.com/unsplash_527bf56961712_1.JPG"/);
  width: 1200px;
  height: 800px;

  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.content {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="/content"/>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis aliquam erat in ante malesuada, facilisis semper nulla semper. Phasellus sapien neque, faucibus in malesuada quis, lacinia et libero. Sed sed turpis tellus. Etiam ac aliquam tortor, eleifend rhoncus metus. Ut turpis massa, sollicitudin sit amet molestie a, posuere sit amet nisl. Mauris tincidunt cursus posuere. Nam commodo libero quis lacus sodales, nec feugiat ante posuere. Donec pulvinar auctor commodo. Donec egestas diam ut mi adipiscing, quis lacinia mauris condimentum. Quisque quis odio venenatis, venenatis nisi a, vehicula ipsum. Etiam at nisl eu felis vulputate porta.</p>
  <p>Fusce ut placerat eros. Aliquam consequat in augue sed convallis. Donec orci urna, tincidunt vel dui at, elementum semper dolor. Donec tincidunt risus sed magna dictum, quis luctus metus volutpat. Donec accumsan et nunc vulputate accumsan. Vestibulum tempor, erat in mattis fringilla, elit urna ornare nunc, vel pretium elit sem quis orci. Vivamus condimentum dictum tempor. Nam at est ante. Sed lobortis et lorem in sagittis. In suscipit in est et vehicula.</p>
</div>;';
}
function foot() {
echo '<div id="footer" style="background-image: url(images/footer.png);background-color:#ADFF2F;clear:both;text-align:center;">
<button>
<marquee bgcolor="Black" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:16px; color:#7FFF00;">
<b>
bla bla bla bla bla </marquee></button>
</div>';
}
?>
```

When I run this script, it gives only a blank page, where did I go wrong? If possible I want my page to be in PHP not HTML.

**UPDATE** Thanks for all the help and the critics, I've successfully called the functions but the css is still not working, it now shows the text but with a white background in it, it should give me an image background on my page. Here's the script:

```
<?php
function ceklogin(){
    session_start();
    if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] != 1) {
        header("Location: login.php");
        exit;
    }}
function css(){
echo '
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>OpenWrt Angel Beats! Edition</title>
<div align="center">
<style type=”text/css”>
.content:before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;

  display: block;
  background-image: url("/http://666a658c624a3c03a6b2-25cda059d975d2f318c03e90bcf17c40.r92.cf1.rackcdn.com/unsplash_527bf56961712_1.JPG"/);
  width: 1200px;
  height: 800px;

  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.content {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="/content"/>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis aliquam erat in ante malesuada, facilisis semper nulla semper. Phasellus sapien neque, faucibus in malesuada quis, lacinia et libero. Sed sed turpis tellus. Etiam ac aliquam tortor, eleifend rhoncus metus. Ut turpis massa, sollicitudin sit amet molestie a, posuere sit amet nisl. Mauris tincidunt cursus posuere. Nam commodo libero quis lacus sodales, nec feugiat ante posuere. Donec pulvinar auctor commodo. Donec egestas diam ut mi adipiscing, quis lacinia mauris condimentum. Quisque quis odio venenatis, venenatis nisi a, vehicula ipsum. Etiam at nisl eu felis vulputate porta.</p>
  <p>Fusce ut placerat eros. Aliquam consequat in augue sed convallis. Donec orci urna, tincidunt vel dui at, elementum semper dolor. Donec tincidunt risus sed magna dictum, quis luctus metus volutpat. Donec accumsan et nunc vulputate accumsan. Vestibulum tempor, erat in mattis fringilla, elit urna ornare nunc, vel pretium elit sem quis orci. Vivamus condimentum dictum tempor. Nam at est ante. Sed lobortis et lorem in sagittis. In suscipit in est et vehicula.</p>
</div>;';
}
css();
function foot() {
echo '<div id="footer" style="background-image: url(images/footer.png);background-color:#ADFF2F;clear:both;text-align:center;">
<button>
<marquee bgcolor="Black" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:16px; color:#7FFF00;">
<b>
blablablabla </marquee></button>
</div>';
}
foot();
?>
```

Comment: You never call the functions that will echo the output.

Comment: Why would you ever use functions like this?

Comment: Don't use `echo` to print long CSS/Javascript/HTML.  Learn how to close PHP tags and reopen them like everyone else.

Comment: @sjagr There will always be developers who take square code and try to jam it into round holes.

Comment: Guys please check out my updated post, the css is still not working

Comment: Your CSS is not working because this isn't a valid path: `/http://666a658c624a3c03a6b2-25cda059d975d2f318c03e90bcf17c40.r92.cf1.rackcdn.com/unsplash_527bf56961712_1.JPG` get rid of the first forward slash before the `http://`. In fact, why do you have these forward slashes in such weird places? You know they effectively do nothing in those spots, right? e.g. `<div class="/content"/>`... nothing.

Comment: Still not working `background-image: url(http://666a658c624a3c03a6b2-25cda059d975d2f318c03e90bcf17c40.r92.cf1.rackcdn.com/unsplash_527bf56961712_1.JPG);`

Comment: Convert the image to Base 64 (http://www.base64-image.de/) and use "background-image: url('data:image/png;base64, [Base 64 data goes here]);"  Be sure you server is gzipping your pages.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the functions if you want to use it that way but I suggest you open and close your php tags instead of creating functions...

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] != 1) {
        header("Location: login.php");
        exit;
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>OpenWrt Angel Beats! Edition</title>

    <style type=”text/css”>
        .content:before {
            content: "";
            position: fixed;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            z-index: -1;
            display: block;
            background-image: url("http://666a658c624a3c03a6b2-25cda059d975d2f318c03e90bcf17c40.r92.cf1.rackcdn.com/unsplash_527bf56961712_1.JPG");
            width: 1200px;
            height: 800px;
            -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
            -moz-filter: blur(5px);
            -o-filter: blur(5px);
            -ms-filter: blur(5px);
            filter: blur(5px);
        }

        .content {
             position: fixed;
             left: 0;
             right: 0;
             z-index: 0;
             margin-left: 20px;
             margin-right: 20px;
        }

        #footer {
            background-image: url(images/footer.png);
            background-color:#ADFF2F;
            clear:both;
            text-align:center;
        }

        #footer marquee {
            font-family:Arial;
            font-size:16px;
            color:#7FFF00;
            background-color: black;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="/content"/>
        <p> .... </p>
        <p> .... </p>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <button>
            <marquee><b>blablablabla</b></marquee>
        </button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: downvoting without a comment is great people. This is answer to OP. Just because its not the correct way to program doesn't make it incorrect

Comment: Although technically true, he needs to call the functions, and answer that doesn't complain about a developer printing out long HTML code in `echo` is just plain incomplete.

Comment: Actually @developerwjk is saying you should be complaining about the horrendous use of `echo`, and since you didn't, you're encouraging bad form in a bad answer.

Comment: @ developerwjk, It's the answer. I've edited to include the correct method of creating the page. All you did was complain instead of showing him the correct method. How is that in any way helpful?

Comment: Guys please check out my updated post, the css is still not working

Comment: Using an include rather than a redirect header saves a complete HTML round trip.  
checklogin does not need to be a function but code remains at top before anything is output by echo.
Styles should be in the HEAD CSS, not inline.

Comment: @Misunderstood, I was still in the midst of editing. Its a lot to do in a tiny textarea on SO. And the function call is fine. It demonstrates how to use functions which the OP lacks sense of. The call to the function was at the top which is what matters. I've updated to include the PHP without the function.

Comment: Only use functions where it serves a purpose. Like being called from multiple code points.  Calling a function once is a waste of CPU, as the the current state must be PUSHED on to the stack then POPPED when the function completes. When the code in a function is minimal then it is better to repeat the functions code where the function would be called.

Comment: @Misunderstood, I am well aware of the additional overhead of a function call. My point was that the OP was defining the functions (useless as it may be) and not calling them. I was demonstrating the call as it is needed to run any function.

Comment: @zgr024 I was Misunderstoood.  My comment was for the OP not you.  Our Answers are nearly the same.  I certainly would not criticize you.

Answer (score 0):

All kinds of problems.  This should fix everything.  Untested.
Correct syntax for echo is:

```
echo <<<EOT
  CSS / HTML
EOT;
```

**PHP**

```
 <?php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] != 1) {
  include 'login.php';
  exit;
}
echo <<<EOT
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>OpenWrt Angel Beats! Edition</title>
<style type="text/css">
.contentBefore {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  display: block;
  background-image: url("/http://666a658c624a3c03a6b2-25cda059d975d2f318c03e90bcf17c40.r92.cf1.rackcdn.com/unsplash_527bf56961712_1.JPG"/);
  width: 1200px;
  height: 800px;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
#content {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
#footer{background-image: url(images/footer.png);background-color:#ADFF2F;clear:both;text-align:center;}
marquee{
  background:#000; 
  font:400 1em Arial;
  color:#7FFF00>
}
</style></head><body><div id="content">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis aliquam erat in ante malesuada, facilisis semper nulla semper. Phasellus sapien neque, faucibus in malesuada quis, lacinia et libero. Sed sed turpis tellus. Etiam ac aliquam tortor, eleifend rhoncus metus. Ut turpis massa, sollicitudin sit amet molestie a, posuere sit amet nisl. Mauris tincidunt cursus posuere. Nam commodo libero quis lacus sodales, nec feugiat ante posuere. Donec pulvinar auctor commodo. Donec egestas diam ut mi adipiscing, quis lacinia mauris condimentum. Quisque quis odio venenatis, venenatis nisi a, vehicula ipsum. Etiam at nisl eu felis vulputate porta.</p>
<p>Fusce ut placerat eros. Aliquam consequat in augue sed convallis. Donec orci urna, tincidunt vel dui at, elementum semper dolor. Donec tincidunt risus sed magna dictum, quis luctus metus volutpat. Donec accumsan et nunc vulputate accumsan. Vestibulum tempor, erat in mattis fringilla, elit urna ornare nunc, vel pretium elit sem quis orci. Vivamus condimentum dictum tempor. Nam at est ante. Sed lobortis et lorem in sagittis. In suscipit in est et vehicula.</p>
</div>
<div id="footer"">
<button>
<marquee 
<b>
bla bla bla bla bla </marquee></button>
</div>';
EOT
?>
```

Comment: It makes zero sense to position the #content as fixed as that would be the default.  You can remove the z-index:0 too (superfluous).

Comment: It makes zero sense to position the #content as fixed as that would be the default.  You can remove the z-index:0 too (superfluous).  Margin-left should probably padding like "padding: 1.25em 0;" There will be a battle between margin-left and "position left" if you were to keep the position and margin. Also em is more flexible than px and is a W3C preferred best practice.  1em represents the Browser's default font size which is very typically 16px.